# Place SWF as a background image. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, swfobject

```
<div id="moldura3" runat="server" style="z-index: 0" wmode="transparent">
<object width="475px" height="75px">
<embed src="animation/fundo.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800px" height="600px"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

It is possible put animated image (format swf) in background in a HTML page? I know with format gif, it works, but the quality this format is sucks... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this page. I believe that this is what you are looking for.

http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_flashbackground.html

Comment: Works like a sharm! Ty ;)